# jquery: catch mouseup for the scroller (even if mouseup is not on the scroller)

Tags: jquery, events, scrollbar, jquery-1.9, mouseup

I'm using a scroller from http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

```
$("#sample-minimal").noUiSlider({
     range: [0, 100]
    ,start: [20, 80]
    ,connect: true
});
```

Everything is fine.

I want to fire an event when the scroller was moved to another position right after mouseup.

```
$("#sample-minimal").mouseup(function() {
//works fine, but it doesn't fire if the mouse was down on the scroller, pulled to another position OUT OF THE SCROLLER and then mouseup
//it works only if the mouse is above the scroller
});
```

So what I want actually is not the mouseup event of `sample-minimal`, but mouseup on any part of the page WHEN the mousedown of `sample-minimal` was trigged (two events all together). As result it actually has the same behavior as the scroller has.

How to make it?

Thank you.

Comment: `$("sample-minimal")` typo ? it should be `$("#sample-minimal")`

Comment: Thank you for pointing the typo! Just fixed.